# Laravel- json_decode returns array but cannot echo array values in Laravel 9

Tags: php, arrays, json, php-8, laravel-9

So I have a Json data in my Database like below:-

```
$json = ["16502735051.jpg","16502735052.jpg","16502735053.jpg","16502735055.jpg"];
```

Now I decoded this JSON into an Array like below:-

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
```

when I print this arr using print_r it returns as below:-

```
Array ( [0] => 16502735051.jpg [1] => 16502735052.jpg [2] => 16502735053.jpg [3] => 16502735054.jpg [4] => 16502735055.jpg )
```

The prob occurs when I try to get the value from the array. I write this:-

```
echo $arr[0]
```

It return error. Shows:- **Trying to access array offset on value of type null**

Comment: When I run your code here https://3v4l.org/jBrOo it works fine. Maybe make sure that `$arr` is really an array before your `echo`

Comment: Hi, Eddy. Thanks for your prompt reply. You are right. I have found the issue. See my answer below. It was my bad that I only inserted JSON data in one row but decoding for every rows in the table. I should have checked the data-table before running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. It's not a bug or something. The problem was happening because, I have three rows in the DB table. **Only one of them has Json Value.** That's why other rows were returning `null` this Laravel returned Fatal error and stopped the script.